# How can I select nth element on wards using xpath from a list of elements

Tags: xpath

I have a list of elements like the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

If I want to select all td elements I can use `tr/td` and if I want to select 2nd element I can use `tr/td[2]`. 
If I want to get all elements after 2nd one how can I write XPath selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required elements:

```
//tr/td[position()>2]
```

This should allow you to get 3, 4, 5... `td` elements based on index

Also you can fetch elements based on text content:

```
//tr/td[.="2"]/following-sibling::td
```